# Como resgatar os valores contidos em um span com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Como pegar os valores que estão dentro de um `span`? Por exemplo:

```
 <?php
    $total_prod = $this->totalRegistros($sql_prod);
    $preco=$this->getPreco();

    for($j=0;$j<$total_prod;$j++){
       echo"
          <div>
             <a href='#' class='click'>
                <span id='valorSpan'> $preco </span>
             </a>
          </div>
       ";
    }
 ?>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#click').click(function(){
          pegarPreco = parseFloat(valoSpam);
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade com o código que tem terá de ser:

```
var spans = $('.click > span'); // ou somente $('.click span');
```

Isto porque não pode ter IDs duplicadas. Ou seja: usar `$('#valorSpan');` vai retornar só o primeiro encontrado.

Se mudar o HTML/PHP para usar classes :

```
for ($j=0; $j < $total_prod; $j++){
   echo "
      <div>
         <a href='#' class='click'>
            <span class='valorSpan'> $preco </span>
         </a>
      </div>
   ";
}
```

então pode fazer:

```
var spans = $('.valorSpan');
```

**Prém:** Na pergunta fala de como resgatar valores de um `span` e o código que usa no event handler aponta para a ancora `$('#click')` procurando por ID. Note que o seletor CSS para ID é `#` e classe é `.`.

Não sei bem porque usa uma ancora `<a>` aí, eu faria sem ancora, só com o `span`. Mas mantendo a sua estrutura de HTML, mudando só para `class='valorSpan' fica aqui um código a funcionar: http://jsfiddle.net/50g5oxaw/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click span').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pegarPreco = parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
        alert(pegarPreco);
    });
});
```

Se, como indicou no comentário tem mais código dentro da ancora e você precisa de ir buscar o valor do span, pode usar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pegarPreco = parseFloat($(this).find('span').html());
        alert(pegarPreco);
    });
});
```

Comment: foi erro meu eu, troquei o "." por "#", mas acho que a resposta que você me deu não me serve, pois dentro da tag  "<a>" tem mais conteúdo que eu preciso pegar, teria outra maneira de resgatar este valor sem clicar diretamente em cima da tag "span"?
Não sei se expliquei direito, caso não entenda eu refaço a pergunta com um codigo mais completo

Comment: @Vinícius juntei mais uma solução no final da resposta. É importante colocar o código real na pergunta. Se não vou estar a adaptar a minha resposta até saber o seu código todo.

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu precisava :D, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

No teu código de JavaScript, tens:

```
$('#click').click(function(){ ... }
```

que vai anexar um evento aos elementos com o ID `click`. Contudo, na tua markup HTML presente na pergunta não tens nenhum elemento com o ID `click`.

Podes resolver o problema de duas maneiras:

1. **Evento de clique para cada elemento**

   Anexar evento de clique a cada `<a/>` que vai apanhar o valor dentro da `span` contida nessa `<a/>` fazendo uso do método [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

   **PHP**

   ```php
   <?php
   // ...
   echo '
   <div>
       <a href="#" class="click">
           <span class="valorSpan">'.$preco.'</span>
       </a>
   </div>';
   // ...
   ?>
   ```

   **jQuery**

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.click').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var pegarPreco = parseFloat($(this).find('.valorSpan').html());
       });
   });
   ```
2. **Delegação do clique**

   Se envolveres toda a markup numa `<div/>`, podes anexar um único evento a essa `<div/>` com delegação aos elementos `<a/>` contidos na mesma fazendo uso do método [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

   **PHP**

   ```php
   <?php
   echo '<div id="minhaWrapper">';

   // ...
   echo '
   <div>
       <a href="#" class="click">
           <span class="valorSpan">'.$preco.'</span>
       </a>
   </div>';
   // ...

   echo '</div>';
   ?>
   ```

   **jQuery**

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#minhaWrapper').on("click", 'a', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var pegarPreco = parseFloat($(this).find('.valorSpan').html());
       });
   });
   ```

Ambas as soluções lidam com o teu problema.

A segunda abordagem é preferível e válida se estiveres com jQuery V1.7 ou superior, pois resulta num único evento delegado a múltiplos elementos na página.